# What repository should be set in set :repo_url "" in deploy.rb for capistrano?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

According to [this](https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/16.04) description I have to set a repository in the deploy.rb file.

```
set :application, "my_app_name"
set :repo_url, "git@example.com:me/my_repo.git"
```

I assume this is the source code of my app, is that correct? At the moment I have my app repository on a cloud9 server. To deploy the app I type `cap production deploy` on the development system. So, do I have to put in the url and path of the cloud9 server? That seems weird, because I deploy from that server. Or is this file transferred to the production system that then pulls the data from the development environment? Does this mean, I need a passwordless ssh connection from a cloud 9 server to the production server or vice versa? Or do I need to push my data to a third system?

Comment: `repo_url` _Must be a valid URL for the used SCM_. For [Reference](https://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/configuration/)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/configuration/), `repo_url` must be set appropriately and the deployed server must be able to connect to it. The reason is that by defaut, capistrano will try to pull code from the `repo` to the deployed server instead of pushing your code directly.